# error in qr factorization algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-factorization

I am supposed to implement the QR factorization using Matlab, and then test it on the matrix A = [1 2; 1 1; 2 3; 2 2].
This is the code I tried to write until now. But I am getting some errors and I'm not sure where the problem is.
Can anyone spot it?

```
A = [1 2; 1 1; 2 3; 2 2];
m = 4
Q=A;
Q(:,1) = A(:,1)/norm(A(:,1));
K = eye(m);
for j=2:n 
Q(:,j) = ((K - Q(:,j-1)*Q(:,j-1)')*A(:,j))/norm((K - Q(:,j-1)*Q(:,j-1)')*A(:,j));
K = K - Q(:,j-1)*Q(:,j-1)';
end
R=Q'*A;
```

Comment: `A` only has 2 columns, but in your loop when `j=3` you are trying to access the third column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop runs from `2:n`, but you haven't defined n.  You simply need to define n with:

```
A = [1 2; 1 1; 2 3; 2 2];
[m,n] = size(A);
```

When I make this addition, I can evaluate Q*R and get

```
>> Q*R

ans =

    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0000    1.0000
    2.0000    3.0000
    2.0000    2.0000
```

Note that defining `m,n` this way lets you generalize to use any matrix `A` (assuming m>=n).

Comment: @NorméliaDaltoé for future questions its immensely helpful if you provide the encountered errors in full so people can help you without guessing at what your problem is.